# What floors are cage keys on?

Tags: enter-the-gungeon

Are Cage Keys always located on the same floor as Cages?

I found a cage on Floor 3 in one of my runs, but didn't find a Cage Key to unlock it.

However, there was an area of the floor I couldn't reach because it was behind a spiked floor that I needed some sort of flight (i.e. Jetpack) to reach.

Comment: And by the way, a spiked floor can be walked on without the need of a jetpack, you just have to run across

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, a cage key can be found at the same floor that the cage is, but if you didn't find it in the rooms, then you have to beat the boss to get the key

Comment: In fact, you can't take cage keys between floors.  They disappear when you enter a new floor.